# nltk python 3 how do you return true if a noun is in the user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nltk, pos-tagger

I am using nltk and this method shown bellow should work it should print "noun found"
 if there is a noun in the input. The problem is that it doesn't, could someone show 
    me how to do this Thank you!

```
NOUN_CODES = {
    'NN',  # Noun, base form
    'NNP',  
    'NNS',  
    'NNPS',

    def Command_Noun_Check(what_person_said_l,what_person_said_l_wt):
                        Command_Noun_Result = nltk.pos_tag(what_person_said_l_wt)
                        print (Command_Noun_Result)
                        for x in Command_Noun_Result:

                            if x in NOUN_CODES:

                                print ("Noun Found")
                                return True
                            else:
                                return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple function should return all the nouns in a sentence. Remember that nltk.pos_tag requires the sentence to be tokenized, and the value returned by nltk.pos_tag is an array of tuples.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize as wt

NOUN_CODES = ['NN', 'NNP'] # input any codes you want here

def check_nouns(sentence):
    tokenized = wt(sentence)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
    return [i[0] for i in tags if i[1] in NOUN_CODES]
```

In your code, I'm assuming that what_person_said_l_wt is tokenized. In this case, I'd modify it in the following way (with better formatting and keeping in mind the indentation):

```
 NOUN_CODES = ['NN','NNP','NNS','NNPS']

 def Command_Noun_Check(what_person_said_l,what_person_said_l_wt):
                        Command_Noun_Result = nltk.pos_tag(what_person_said_l_wt)
                        print (Command_Noun_Result)
                        for x in Command_Noun_Result:

                            if x[1] in NOUN_CODES:

                                print ("Noun Found")
                                return True
                            else:
                                return False
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, do you think you could explain why it wasn't working?

Comment: `nltk.pos_tag(text)` returns a list as: `[('Sergei', 'NN')]`. So, you should check for the 2nd element of the tuple and hence in your code `if x in NOUN_CODES` should be  `if x[1] in NOUN_CODES`